# How to get posts in different language from WPML Plugin

Tags: wp-query, plugin-wpml

i'm using [Thermal-Api](http://thermal-api.com/) plugin in order to define a REST WS to get posts in JSON format.

My Client uses WPML to translate posts and i need to pass to WP_Query the language set in front-end side.

Is there a particular parameter to pass to WP_Query to select only the post in that language or is there a way to change dynamically "ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE" in order to retrieve what i need??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming `$new_lang` holds the desired two letter language code (e.g. 'fr'), you can do this:

```
global $sitepress;
$current_lang = $sitepress->get_current_language(); //save current language
$sitepress->switch_lang($new_lang);
//...run query here; if you use WP_Query or get_posts make sure you set suppress_filters=0 ... 
$sitepress->switch_lang($current_lang); //restore previous language
```

For more info, check http://wpml.org/documentation/support/achieving-wpml-compatibility-for-your-themes-and-plugins/debugging-theme-compatibility/